# ¿Como insertar datos por defecto en Python-Flask evitando que se dupliquen?

Tags: python, flask

Cuando trabajas con Flask en el modo debug, Werzeug ejecuta una hilo hijo de tu aplicacion el cual recibira los cambios que hagas al codigo fuente y los actualizara en vivo.

Puedes desactivar esta opcion del hilo hijo pero por lo que leia no es recomendable, ni siquiera al estar fuera del modo debug.

Por lo tanto se necesita verificar la existencia de los modelos cargados en Flask, para insertarlos o no.

Busque en el sitio en ingles y encontre esta funcion:

```
def get_or_create(session, model, **kwargs):
    '''
    Creates an object or returns the object if exists
    credit to Kevin @ StackOverflow
    from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546207/does-sqlalchemy-have-an-equivalent-of-djangos-get-or-create
    '''
    instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
    if instance:
        return instance
    else:
        instance = model(**kwargs)
        session.add(instance)
        session.commit()
        return instance
```

Esta funcion permite verificar que los modelos no hallan sido creados antes.

El problema:

No se en que parte del codigo colocar la llamada a la funcion.

Trate agregandolo directamente al archivo models.py

```
from app import db

def get_or_create(session, model, **kwargs):
    '''
    Creates an object or returns the object if exists
    credit to Kevin @ StackOverflow
    from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546207/does-sqlalchemy-have-an-equivalent-of-djangos-get-or-create
    '''
    instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
    if instance:
        return instance
    else:
        instance = model(**kwargs)
        session.add(instance)
        session.commit()
        return instance

def fill_database():
    #: UserAccess
    administrador = get_or_create(session, UserAccess, description="Administrador")
    jefe_de_departamento = get_or_create(session, UserAccess, description="Jefe de Departamento")
    personal_de_departamento = get_or_create(session, UserAccess, description="Personal de Departamento")

class UserAccess(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    useraccess__user = db.relationship("User", backref="useraccess__user")

fill_database()
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

**working outside of request context**

Este es mi app.py

```
# -*- coding = utf8 -*-
from flask import Flask
from flask import abort
from flask import flash
from flask import g
from flask import redirect
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import session
from flask import url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from config import DevelopmentConfig

from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app(app)
        db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

¿Como puedo utilizar esa funcion para llenar mi base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ocurre al ejecutar una aplicación con el modo `debug=True, esto debido a que al ejecutar con ese parámetro en True, Flask utilizara una segunda aplicación la cual recibirá los cambios y luego actualizara la primera, por tanto ejecutara de nuevo el código de la inserción, por tanto lo mas practico seria:

**A-** Ejecutar la función y luego comentarla

**B-** Ejecutar la función y dejar la aplicación en modo de producción, es decir, `DEBUG = False`